# Complete rxjs observable afer not emitting values for x seconds

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I need to write observable that will complete after there hasn't been new values for x amount of time.

What i have written myself is:

.pipe(takeUntil(timer(1000))).subscribe();

The problem with this is that it will simply complete observable after 1 second. I need to code behaviour where this timer refreshes when there is new value emitted. So lets say: 50 values are emitted -> nothing happens for 1 second -> observable completes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to have a 1s [timeout](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timeout) that resets on each emission:

```js
stream$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((value) => concat(of(value), NEVER.pipe(timeout(1000)))),
    catchError((e: Error) =>
      e instanceof TimeoutError ? EMPTY : throwError(() => e)
    )
  )
```

For completeness I've created a small demo:

```js
const stream$ = concat(
  of(1).pipe(delay(500)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(10)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(950)),
  of(4).pipe(delay(1050)), // our final stream should complete at this point because it's taking up more than 1s
  of(5)
);

stream$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((value) => concat(of(value), NEVER.pipe(timeout(1000)))),
    catchError((e: Error) =>
      e instanceof TimeoutError ? EMPTY : throwError(() => e)
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (x) => console.log('Received', x),
    error: (x) => console.log('Error', x),
    complete: () => console.log('Complete'),
  });
```

Which outputs:

```
Received 1
Received 2
Received 3
Complete
```

As expected.

Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-thsvpe?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).